# How to find amount of hours in a day in NodaTime?

Tags: .net, nodatime

I'm writing a test app to reproduce some data writing scenario - a task that runs each hour.
 For that purpose I need to know how many times it will execute - how many hours there are on a given day. I tried to do that like this: 
`Period.Between(localDateTimeStart.Date, localDateTimeStart.Date.PlusDays(1), PeriodUnits.Hours)` 
but it gives me ArgumentException saying `Units contains time units: Hours`. What would be the idiomatic way to do that in NodaTime? Or is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between two *local* date/time values, there will always be 24 hours. It sounds like you're interested in a date in a particular *zone*, in which case you want:

```
 var startOfDay = zone.AtStartOfDay(date);
 var startOfNextDay = zone.AtStartOfDay(date.PlusDays(1));
 var duration = startOfNextDay.ToInstant() - startOfDay.ToInstant();
 var hours = duration.Ticks / NodaConstants.TicksPerHour;
```

(In Noda Time 2.0, `Duration` has a `TotalHours` property making this easier. That would return a `double` value, whereas here `hours` is a `long` due to the types of the operands. Be aware that it could lose information if the time zone has a transition of (say) half an hour.)

Comment: thanks for the clarification. so if I hit a day when transition was not integer amount of hours then I just use TicksPerMinute/Second properies?

Comment: @chester: Yes, you could - it depends on what you want to do, really.